# How to prevent pandas from only assigning value from one df to column of another for only one row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id   col1     col2
1    2         3 
4    5         6
7    8         9
```

when I go to add a new column and assign a value like this:

```
df['new_col'] = old_df['email']
```

The assignment only assigns the value to the first like so:

```
id   col1     col2   new_col
 1    2         3     a@a.com
 4    5         6     NaN
 7    8         9     NaN
```

How do I have the assignment for all rows like so:

```
id   col1     col2   new_col
 1    2         3     a@a.com
 4    5         6     a@a.com
 7    8         9     a@a.com
```

edit:

old_df:

```
id   col3     col4   email
 1    2         3     a@a.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas series assignment works by *index*. Since `old_df` only contains index `0`, only index `0`, i.e. the first row, of `df` is updated.

For your particular problem, you can use [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) and assign a scalar to a series:

```
df['new_col'] = old_df['email'].iat[0]
```

This works because Pandas broadcasts scalars to the *whole* series irrespective of index.

Comment: that helps in understanding, thank you so much it works!